# pagination logic when using css flexbox

Tags: python

I want to implement pagination for the records displayed on screen as count of records in books can be from 50 to 500 records. I've used CSS flexbox. I've multiple such tabs created using radio button in my actual code.
Please if anyone can help about this.

--- app.py ---

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/catalog_db")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = '12345678'
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"

@app.route('/bookList')
def booklist():
    statement = text("""SELECT title,author FROM book order by id""")
    books = db.execute(statement)

    return render_template("BookList0.html", books=books)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

--- BookList0.html ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styleTest.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mytabs">
          <!-------------------------------- First Tab begins------------------------->
          <input type="radio" id="tg2d" name="mytabs" checked="checked">
          <label for="tg2d">Book Data</label>
          <div class="tab">
            <div class="table-container-1">
                <p></p>
                <div class="table-row heading">
                    <div class="row-item-h1">Book Related Details</div>
                </div>
                {% for book in books %}
                    {% if loop.first %}
                        <div class="table-row heading">
                            <div class="row-item-h2">Title</div>
                            <div class="row-item-h2">Author</div>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="table-row">
                        <div class="row-item-b">{{book.title}}</div>
                        <div class="row-item-b">{{book.author}}</div>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <div class="table-row">
                        <div class="row-item-b1">No matching records found.</div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

--- styleTest.css ---

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
    font-family: 'Garamond', sans-serif;
    color: #000080;
}

input[type='radio']{
            accent-color: navy;
        }

.mytabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.mytabs input[type="radio"] {
    display: none
}

.mytabs label {
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.mytabs .tab {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    order: 1;
    display: none;
}

.mytabs input[type='radio']:checked + label + .tab {
    display: block;
}

.mytabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: #fff;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
}

.form-group label {
    padding: 15px;
    margin:  5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 4px 4px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=submit], input[type=button] {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 6px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.table-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background-color: white;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.table-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.heading {
  background-color: #ececec;
  color: #000080;
}

.row-item-h1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row-item-h2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row-item-b {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row-item-b1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.message {
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #DC143C;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: please reduce the amount of code, most of it does not seem relevant at all. For example, the python-part does not matter because your endpoint will always return the same html-page - if your problem is to do with html, post only that.

Comment: also be more precise with what you want to achieve with the flexbox

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make an API call from frontend instead of dumping everything to user on first request.

`From frontend use JavaScript to request for the data and in backend return data with limitations of item example 10 per request` -> `Then store the data id in user frontend` -> `Check if user scroll to the button or any other method u could think of` -> `Request to the API again also include the stored data id to payload` -> `In backend query to database with same limitations and also exclude the stored data id from user. In this way the result will return the new items except the items that user already loaded.` This can go on infinitely without making your backend stress out so much.